# Bug in Integrate vs NIntegrate in mma8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, integrate, mathematica-8

What is going on here (Mathematica version 8.x):

```
NIntegrate[Log[1/2 + Sqrt[1/4 - 1/(4 x^2)]]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}]
--> -0.171007

Integrate[Log[1/2 + Sqrt[1/4 - 1/(4 x^2)]]/x, {x, 1, Infinity}] // N
--> 0.171007
```

The `NIntegrate[]` value is correct. I have run into problems with `PrincipalValue` selections before but a) those have been fixed in mma8 and b) this integral doesn't, or at least shouldn't, have poles in the integration region.

EDIT: Thanks to people suggesting solutions to this problem, a general solution would be, e.g., using exclusively `NIntegrate`. However, I am interested in finding out why specifically this happens and whether thus this bug is predictable.

Comment: I've got Mma7, both gives -0.171007.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for confirming this. I clarified the title and question as to what version of mma is affected.

Comment: Timo, congratulations on 2000 rep.

Comment: Woot woot, party at my user profile page in five :-P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in `Integrate`, I am afraid. As a workaround, do the change of variables `x->u^(-1/2)`:

```
In[12]:= Log[1/2 + Sqrt[1/4 - 1/(4*x^2)]]/x Dt[x]/Dt[u] /. 
 x -> 1/Sqrt[u]

Out[12]= Log[1/2 + Sqrt[1/4 - u/4]]/(2 u)
```

Then

```
In[14]:= Integrate[%, {u, 1, 0}]

Out[14]= 1/24 (-\[Pi]^2 + Log[8] Log[16])

In[15]:= N[%]

Out[15]= -0.171007
```

This agrees with `NIntegrate`.

Comment: A better workaround is using exclusively `NIntegrate`, do you have any idea why that change of variables corrects the outcome?

Comment: The reason that the incorrect computation of anti-derivative (has wrong sign). This gives `ad = Integrate[f = Log[1/2 + Sqrt[1/4 - 1/(4*x^2)]]/x, x]; D[ad, x] + f // FullSimplify[#, x > 1] &` zero. This explains the wrong sign. In v7 this anti-derivative remains unevaluated, and so is the definite integrand. After the change of variables, both the anti-derivative and the definite integral are correct.

Comment: Do you mean that in v7 only the definite integral is evaluated and in v8 there is an intermediate step via the indefinite integral (anti-derivative)?

Comment: No, I mean in v7 neither definite, not indefinite symbolic integral evaluates. Applying `N` to the unevaluated `Integrate` automatically calls `NIntegrate`. In v8 both anti-derivative and the definite integral are off by a sign.